# MPEG-4 Decoder Vs MPEG 2 Decoder Vs 3GP Decoder, which is faster and why?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mpeg-4, 3gp, mpeg-2

On the Android platform with ARM &/ DSP which decoder will be faster: MPEG-4 or MPEG-2 or 3GP? And why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Faster" is a relative term. Impossible to answer given the information in your question. But speaking in general terms, MPEG-4 is a **lot** more complex than MPEG-2. The list of features are too long to list here... One of the features in MPEG-4 ASP is [qpel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qpel) that is not present in MPEG-2.

BTW, 3GP is a container-format and not a decoder. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3GP_and_3G2)

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for my incomplete question. well I have to develop a prototype of video application involving first decoding the frames and then some processing. Now my requirement is such that I want that for a given frame size (with any encoding I am free to choose), the decoding time should be minimum. I understand that the way frames are decoded in mpeg2 and mpeg 4 might be different, one faster than other.

Comment: [I found this one useful](http://www.pcworld.com/article/213612/all_about_video_codecs_and_containers.html)

Comment: Then I'd recommend to go for MPEG-4 VSP (Visual Simple profile). You'd be able to find a lot of references towards it. Implementations available by DivX, XviD, ffmpeg etc, even included in Android.